# Logs getting cleared after each build

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services

I have implemented Winston logging in my NodeJS Application and deployed it in AWS in a docker container. each time I deploy my application into the AWS the logs are getting cleared as it is creating new docker container for that service but I need my logs to be persistent is there anyway that I can stop my logs fro being cleared

Comment: Link an outside volume for log files to your docker

Comment: Can I know how to do that? @GaneshKarewad

Comment: refer to this link https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/docker-volumes.html let me know if you need a detailed answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have mounted the folder to my EC2 instance then it worked fine